# Codeigniter Sort by date multiple function

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$data['reg'] = $this->register->registerAcc($schoolID); 
$data['upd'] =$this->register->UpdateAcc($schoolID); 
$data['sus'] =$this->register->suspendAcc($schoolID);
$this->load->view('account/accountInfo',$data);
```

This is my code that consist of update,register,and suspend. every function have their own "date/time"

Every end of the function have this code:

> $this->db->order_by('register_Date','DESC'); 
>   every function have it own date, example register_Date , updateAcc_Date

But i have a problem , when i show in the page the list will go from

```
Date           Function       UserName
05-09-2019  Register    Tom
04-09-2019  Register    Bors
01-09-2019  Register    Berry
03-09-2019  Update      Laxy    
05-09-2019  Suspend     Loi
```

What i wanted is

```
Date           Function       UserName
05-09-2019  Register    Tom
05-09-2019  Suspend     Loi
04-09-2019  Register    Bors
03-09-2019  Update      Laxy    
01-09-2019  Register    Berry
```

Comment: Please Add Full sql query in your question. and double check for `register_Date` field exist in database ?

Comment: can you please schema of table? I feel you have not chosen the date field as date time in DB

Comment: sorry for the misinformation every function have it own date, example register_Date , updateAcc_Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set date with same key like `date` in `$data` array and then Use `usort()` function

```
$data = Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [Function] => 'register'
        [datetime] => 2010-05-26 15:59:53
    )

[1] => Array
    (
       [Function] => 'update'
        [datetime] => 2010-05-26 16:04:24
    )

)
 function date_compare($a, $b)
    {
        $t1 = strtotime($a['datetime']);
        $t2 = strtotime($b['datetime']);
        return $t1 - $t2;
    }    
    usort($data, 'date_compare');
    print_r($data);
```